# How to allow Readers to Select Post Order?

Tags: wp-query, archives

I added a select field for every category, tag archive page.

1. Sory By Post Date
2. Sort  By Post Modified Date
3. Sort By (custom field)

When a reader select any of above how to load posts according to selected order.

I have no idea where should I start at least...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is Ajax. You will need to read about how to use Wordpress Ajax ([link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)).

When your visitor click on select field to choose sorting, you need a JS function to handle the data about how to sort and where the visitor in, then a js function to make ajax request to server.

At server here (I mean your theme function) you will need a function to handle request and send the response to client. The handler function here is a WP_Query loop to loop your post according to the order that your visitor chose.

Sorry, I don't have enough time to provide you the code, but I think for a scripter/coder/developer, the direction is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can't I do without Ajax? I mean when reader select, reload that page according reader request?

Comment: You can, by defining the parameter in URL or using post request (turn your select box to a form), but I think ajax will be the better choice.

Comment: Really thanks. Just give me this help please. Assume that I pass wanted things to URL (form). Now according those field I need to change the order. Where should I write that code? I mean where should I call post order function? Where should I put it? Thanks

Comment: You can send request to the same category/archive page. In category/archive template file, at very first, you should put a condition to check if have a GET request(because you put your parm in URL). If it does, change the query to custom loop according to variables you got from the request. If it does not, just process normal loop. For more detail:

   if(your condition) {
   // the custom loop process GET request
   } else {
   // the normal loop of your template
   }